# query to get a count of impressions and related clicks

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cant seem to get this query to give me the right result.

```
select 
    datepart(day, i.timestamp) as [day], 
    i.campaignID, i.creativeID
    , count(distinct i.sessionID) as [Impressions]
    , count(case when e.eventID in (1,2,3) then 1 else 0 end) as Clicks

from impressions i 
left join Events e 
    on i.sessionID = e.sessionID

group by 
    datepart(day, i.timestamp)
    , i.campaignID, i.creative

order by [day]
```

I also tried replacing 1 with e.eventid in the then clause. I'm getting way too many clicks in the result. Events has multiple records per sessionid because many types of events can occur in the same session (rollover, rollout, etc.) the events I'm looking to count would have an eventid of 1, 2, or 3 as these would be the 3 possible links you could click on. What Im looking for is to calculate the click through rate by getting a count of impressions and related clicks, also if there are no clicks I would like it to be reflected as 0 rather then be missing from the results, which is what im getting.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance for your precious time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the second `count` with `sum`, like so:

```
select 
  datepart(day, i.timestamp) as [day], 
  i.campaignID, i.creativeID
  , count(distinct i.sessionID) as [Impressions]
  , sum(case when e.eventID in (1,2,3) then 1 else 0 end) as Clicks

from impressions i 
left join Events e 
  on i.sessionID = e.sessionID

group by 
  datepart(day, i.timestamp)
  , i.campaignID, i.creative

order by [day]
```

Or, you could keep `count` and move the `eventID` filtering to the `where` clause:

```
select 
  datepart(day, i.timestamp) as [day], 
  i.campaignID, i.creativeID
  , count(distinct i.sessionID) as [Impressions]
  , count(e.eventID) as Clicks

from impressions i 
left join Events e 
  on i.sessionID = e.sessionID

where e.eventID in (1,2,3)

group by 
  datepart(day, i.timestamp)
  , i.campaignID, i.creative

order by [day]
```

But I'm suspecting you will need additional filter conditions in your `on` clause. However, I don't know your tables' structure to tell for sure.

Comment: that looks much more likely, thanks! can you explain why sum(1) gives a different result from count(1) ?

Comment: Sure. `count` included every element of your 0/1 series, whether it was 0 or 1 (`count{0,1,1,1,0,0,1}`=7). `sum` adds only 1s, whereas 0s make no diffrence (`sum{0,1,1,1,0,0,1}`=0+1+1+1+0+0+1=4). But all that applies to sets. sum(1) has no difference from count(1), because the first adds up to 1 and the second has 1 element.

Comment: gotcha thanks, im surprised that count includes the zeros - the case structure suggests to me that it would only include a zero if there were no... argh, ok it just dawned on me. *facepalms* - whutta idjut :P